# Shell script wont run in cron as root

Tags: linux, sh, cron

I have the following code in my root cron file:
    `PATH=/opt/someApp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
45 12 * * * /home/ben/MetaBackup/metabackup.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | slacktee.sh -t "Metabase Backup Error" -a "danger"`

slacktee.sh is located in /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin however when i run this metabackup.sh runs ok but slacktee.sh does not. I have tried absolute location for slacktee also but that did not work. The more confusing thing is i put the exact same lines in my user crontab and slacktee works fine. What am i doing wrong? Or is this an issue with slacktee that i need to raise there?

EDIT:
slacktee is available here: https://github.com/course-hero/slacktee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, cron is not finding `slacktee.sh` in its path. You're setting the PATH for the first command, but that setting does not apply to the command after the pipe.

Try using the full path to `slacktree`:

```
... | /usr/local/bin/slacktee.sh -t "Metabase Backup Error" -a "danger"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting stdout and stderr of metabackup.sh to /dev/null , so I think really no output is piped to slacktee.sh and its standard input is empty.

Try removing `> /dev/null`

Comment: Thats not the problem as I had tried piping everything to slacktee.sh. However i found the problem was within slacktee.sh. Its not designed to be used with an account other than the one it was installed with as it creates the config with the url to talk to slack with in the users home directory. This was not available to root. So installing it as root fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with gile !

If there is no output, slacktee won't be able to print anything.

If it's still not working, try to load profile in your command :

```
45 12 * * * . ~/.profile;/home/ben/MetaBackup/metabackup.sh 2>&1 | slacktee.sh -t "Metabase Backup Error" -a "danger"
```

Of course, adapt the file depending on if you are on bash or ksh (.profile or .bash_profile)

Do not forget the ". " in front of your .profile file.

Hope it will help.